# Azure: More DTUs or more shards?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sharding

Basically, I am wondering if anyone has any experience with increasing DTUs v. Sharding.  A DTU is *supposed* to increase performance linearly.  So, if you have a 5 DTUs and you go to 10 DTUs, you should (theoretically) get about twice the performance.

As such, what would be the difference between four SQL shards (each with 5 DTUs) and one 20 DTU database?  What kind of benefit would one see with the four shards as opposed to the one database with more "performance"?

Thanks!

Comment: This is very subjective so I'll ask questions. What sort of load do you have, is it constant or burst? How is the load spread across the shards, is it even or would it be biased to one shard over the others? Rather than have one over the other why not design such that you can use both and use each technique as and when required.

Comment: Great questions!

The load is constant with some large bursts every few minutes.

The load would be spread by splitting "clients" and all of the data that has to do with each one across all of the shards.

It's not that I want to have one over the other, it is that I do not want to over-engineer for performance if just quadrupling the DTUs would achieve _close to_ the same outcome.

Comment: If you have 5 DTUs per shard and you get a burst then I suspect the burst is probably concentrated to one shard (customer), if so are you willing to have the 5 DTUs maxed out and the others idle(ish) - what sort of performance degradation are you willing to accept during a burst when you can't deliver the data to requests as quick as normal? Having a pool of DTUs allows for betting handling of bursts but it will look like you have have a lots of unused DTUs as they are just hanging around for the times of burst.

Comment: Spreading your DTUs into shards ensures that a single burst does not affect customers outside the shard running on constant load. Think on the experience...

Comment: Cool, I get what you are saying.  Any comment on Azure Elastic Scale?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to play with that in anger to give any worthwhile advice

Comment: Also Shards are the way to get around the database space limits (ie: you have a customer that might grow to more than 500GB at some point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting your workload to grow over time, it makes sense to start with a sharded design so you'll have plenty of headroom for increased traffic without having to re-architect later.  But be sure that you don't need to perform queries that join data in different shards.  Overall the performance will be similar to scaling up.  I recommend testing the application to make sure that the bursts are handled gracefully against a 5 DTU database.

One thing to note is that the 5 DTU databases are in Basic edition while the 10 and 20 DTU databases are in Standard edition.  You get more features in Standard and less performance fluctuation:  Standard promises transaction rates per minute, while basic promised transaction rates per hour.  given that, you might do best with a pair of Standard 10 DTU databases as a starting point for sharding.

Elastic Scale for Azure SQL makes it easy to route requests to individual shards and also obtain merged result sets that cross multiple shards, while managing the mapping of data ranges to shards.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I was just using the 5 DTU as an example...I will definitely be going with the standard edition.